# What if your legs would not stop moving in the walking motion

Tags: simulated-worlds

What if your legs would not stop moving in the walking motion. I mean every human if they all moved at the same speed and momentum. What would the world be like now. Just what if.

Comment: "if they all moved at the same speed and momentum." You can have one or the other but you can only have both if all humans have the same mass.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding. Unfortunately, this question doesn't appear to be about worldbuilding. For tips on what sort of questions to ask, I suggest you read this: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every window would require a treadmill type device.
Every office cubicle would contain a large hamster wheel.
The obesity epidemic would be over and feminists would need to find a new hobby horse.

Answer (score 1):

Baugua, the Chinese art of circle walking, would become a very popular way of managing the walking issues.  There's even a martial art, Bauguazhen, which is based off of walking in circles to disrupt the line of attack for your foes.  With or without foes, Baugua is considered one of the approaches to health and well being in China.